# how to append option element and value inside PHP and call inside ajax to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two `<select>`, What I want to achieve is that when I select a data, it calls the ajax that I did then append it's value from another `<select` element and then it has `<option>`.I tried to alert and the success alerts the `<option>`, however when I tried to append it to HTML, it says `[object Object]`, I hope someone can help, and explain to me so that in the future whenever I will encounter problems like this I have a backtrack. Thank you so much.

PHP code is here:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'. $row['name'] .'</option>';
```

HTML and JQuery

```js
function setDept(element) {
  let dept = $(element).val();
  if (dept) {

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "myform.php",
      data: {
        "department": dept
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // alert(response);
        $('#sel_requested_dept').append(response);
      }
    });

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label> Teacher: </label>
   <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="teacher"
    data-live-search="true" onchange="setDept(this)" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled> Select Teacher </option>
     <?php
       $query = "SELECT * FROM teachers";
       $con->next_result();
       $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
       {
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['teacher_name'].'">'. $row['section'] ." - ".  
                $row['teacher_name'] .'</option>';
          }
       }                                               
      ?>
     </select>
   </div>    

<div class="form-group">
  <label> Department </label>
  <select name="request_dept" id="sel_requested_dept" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled> Select Department </option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , show `alert(response);` output as well .

Comment: Hi, it says `<option value="DANA">Science 101 - DANA</option><option value="MACK">Science 101 - MACK</option><option value="RELYN">Science 101 - RELYN</option><option value="MALEN">Science 101 - MALEN</option><option value="MARGE">Science 101 - MARGE</option>`

Comment: It is working fine the data is okay, I just want to make it append to my select element.

Comment: I am not seeing any such behaviour  can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ckv5f9t/) . Maybe problem is somewhere else is this your original code ? also is it selectpicker ?

Comment: Yes this is my code :(

Comment: after appending refresh selectpicker i.e : `$('#sel_requested_dept').selectpicker('refresh');` . Updated code check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ckv5f9t/2/)

Comment: Wow it worked, Why did that happened? is it a bug?

Comment: No its written in [documentation](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh) you need refresh selectpicker after appending new option . Also,  use `.html()` because `append` will append option *without removing previous datas* .

Comment: Okay will add it . Thank you and I should read documentation.

Comment: Hi @Swati is it okay to ask you another question regarding splitting of data? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228981/discussion-between-swati-and--san).

Comment: Hi @Swati sorry for the delayed reply. I hope you will still notice my question, I have already typed the question inside our chat discussion, thank you very much again :->